# Add data into php mysql with single quotes

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code:

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE name like '%$searchText%'");

      while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))

              //$output[]=$e;
              //echo $e['NAME'];
              {
              $name = $e['NAME'];
              $brand = $e['BRAND'];
              $category = $e['CATEGORY'];
              $query = "INSERT INTO table2 (brand, name, category) VALUES ('$brand', '$name', '$category')";
              $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to insert because : " . mysql_error()); 
              }
```

Since in "BRAND", there may be some data like "First's Choice".
In this case, I cannot insert to database due to error.
How can I insert data that contain single quotes?
Thx

Comment: try reading here  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use `mysql_real_escape_string` on the value, which you should be doing anyway. That should properly escape your value for insertion.

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($e['NAME']);
$brand = mysql_real_escape_string($e['BRAND']);
$category = mysql_real_escape_string($e['CATEGORY']);
$query = "INSERT INTO table2 (brand, name, category) VALUES ('$brand', '$name', '$category')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Answer (score 1):

You must use :

- `$brand = mysql_real_escape_string($brand)`

See [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

> string **mysql_real_escape_string** ( string $unescaped_string [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
>
> Escapes special characters in
>   the unescaped_string, taking into account the current character set of
>   the connection so that it is safe to place it in a mysql_query(). If
>   binary data is to be inserted, this function must be used. (..)

Answer (score 1):

```
Try below code 

$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE name like '%$searchText%'");

      while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))

              //$output[]=$e;
              //echo $e['NAME'];
              {
              $name = $e['NAME'];
              $brand = mysql_real_escape_string($e['BRAND']);
              $category = $e['CATEGORY'];
              $query = "INSERT INTO table2 (brand, name, category) VALUES ('$brand', '$name', '$category')";
              $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to insert because : " . mysql_error()); 
              }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of accomplishing that. You can first run an escape string on it:

```
$newbrand = mysql_real_escape_string($brand);
```

and insert $newbrand. When you call it, you have to do strpslashes($newbrand);

OR you could do:

```
$search = array("'");
$newbrand = str_replace($search,'',$brand);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was pulling my hair to solve this, finally i am ok with this solution. [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926852/adding-single-quote-into-mysql-results-with-s-sometimes-but-not-always/21933889#21933889)