# Adding single quote into mysql results with \'s sometimes but not always

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, stripslashes, addslashes

Initially when i try to add a string that have Single quotations the database used to return an error message..

So i added **addslashes** to that string before the query.

> After adding the addslashes, the String looks like this in DataBase.
>   For some reason the backslashes are not always inserted.

[image]

Please suggest me a method for handling quotes after going through this scenario

**Case1: Using Addslashes**

I already have a huge code, where if i use **addslashes** before insertion, i must also use **stripslashes** after select query to remove \ in every result. This will result lot of changes in my controllers and models IN **Codeigniter**.

**Case2: Without addslashes**

If i dont use addslashes or mysql_escape my database doesnot allow me to store single quotes.

I changed the charset to **utf8mb4_general_ci**, but still of no use..
I also made sure that the charset in **config.php** also contains **utf8mb4 charset**.

Any suggestions for an efficient method?

Comment: Doesnt codeigniter add the slashes on its own if you active records? Use active records may be?

Comment: Prepared Statement handles by default, if any characters like single quotes, back slashes, etc are present as part of the data. You not even require to call `mysql_real_escape_string` on the data.

Comment: you can try $this->db->escape(),$this->db->escape_str(), $this->db->escape_like_str()

Comment: I am using active records, but still the problem persists. Do i need to change any configurations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, hope this will be helpful to others

> Update MySql to 5.5.3+ and use charset utf8mb4_general_ci.. Make sure
>   that the datatype is longtext

That's it. No need of using addslashes and stripslashes as far as i know.

It also supports emoji's
Thanks